Blob to Snowflake Data Ingestion using Azure Data factory
I am loading data from azure blob to snowflake using for each in Data factory.
Most of the copy loads are successful, sometimes I am facing the issue as below and sometimes its going smooth.

ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR
[HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL *** failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=503.
,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
[HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL *** failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=503.
,Source=SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll,'

I want to know what is the problem here.. Test connection of linked service looks good.
I have all permissions too. Just want to know what I am missing here.
enabled staging and tried increased with DIU's..

ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL *** failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=503. ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL *** failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=503. ,Source=SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll,'

According to this if the provided URL is incorrect then you may get above error. Ensure you are using correct format of URL. The correct format of URL as follows:
<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com

Instead of using ODBC connector to connect snowflake use Native Linked Service Connector to connect snowflake as shown below:

For more information you can refer to below documents:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier#account-identifier-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region

https://www.mouritech.com/it-technical-articles/using-azure-data-factory-ingest-load-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-snowflake/



URL is correct, which is passing for other activities in debug mode its going smooth. even in Trigger mode passing couple of times. Most of the times pipeline is failing with the above error only..
